# bootstrap-vue toggle expand table row

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

This seems to remain unanswered so here is another attempt at a solution.

Currently in bootstrap-vue, I am rendering a `b-table`. I would like to improve this by having the ability to select a row and collapse/expand an extra div/row/etc to show further information.

In the below snippet you will see what I am trying. The problem is that I can't seem to get the expanded data to span the number of columns in the table. I have tried adding `<tr><td colspan="6"></td></tr>` but it doesn't seem to span like I would expect. Any workarounds for this? Thanks.

```
<b-table
    :items="case.cases"
    :fields="tableFields"
    head-variant="dark">
    <template
        slot="meta.status"
        slot-scope="data">
    <b-badge
        v-b-toggle.collapse1
        :variant="foobar"
        tag="h6">
        {{ data.value }}
    </b-badge>
    </template>
    <template
        slot="@id"
        slot-scope="data">
        <span
            v-b-toggle.collapse1>
            {{ data.value }}
        </span>
        <b-collapse id="collapse1">
            Collapse contents Here
        </b-collapse>
    </template>
</b-table>`
```

Comment: Sounds like you could just use the built in [row-details](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#row-details-support) to achieve this?

Comment: You might check out [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/nardnob/ktnafuhs/)

Comment: @StevenB is correct. `row-details` is your best bet, and it is built in so minimal code is required to use it.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you could use the **Row Details** slot:

> If you would optionally like to display additional record information (such as columns not specified in the fields definition array), you can use the scoped slot `row-details`

```html
<b-table :items="case.cases" :fields="tableFields" head-variant="dark">
  <template slot="meta.status" slot-scope="data">
    <b-button @click="data.toggleDetails">
        {{ data.value }}
    </b-button>
  </template>
  <template slot="row-details" slot-scope="data">
    <b-button @click="data.toggleDetails">
        {{ data.detailsShowing ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} Details }}
    </b-button>
    <div>
       Details for row go here.
       data.item contains the row's (item) record data
       {{ data.item }}
    </div>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

There is a good example in the docs at https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#row-details-support

Answer (score 1):

I (think) I had the same issue, and I came up with a solution which leverages the filtering functionality of the bootstrap-vue `<b-table>` to achieve the effect of expanding and collapsing rows.

There's a minimal example in a JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/adlaws/mk4128dg/

Basically you provide a tree structure for the table like this:

```
[
    {
        columnA: 'John', columnB:'Smith', columnC:'75',
        children:
        [
            { columnA: 'Mary', columnB:'Symes', columnC:'46' },
            { columnA: 'Stan', columnB:'Jones', columnC:'42' },
            { columnA: 'Pat', columnB:'Black', columnC:'38' },
        ]
    }
]
```

The tree is then "flattened" out to rows which can be displayed in a table by the `_flattenTreeStructure()` method. During this process, the rows are also annotated with some extra properties to uniquely identify the row, store the depth of the row (used for indentation), the parent row of the row (if any) and whether or not the row is currently expanded.

Once this is done, the flattened structure can be handed to the `<b-table>` as it is just an array of rows - this is done via the `compute`d property `flattenedTree`.

The main work now is done by the `_filterFunction()` method which provides custom filtering on the table. It works off the state of the `expandedRowIndices` property of the `filterObj` data item.

As the expand/collapse buttons are clicked, the row index (as populated during the flattening process) is inserted as a key into `expandedRowIndices` with a `true` or `false` indicating its current expanded state.

The `_filterFunction()` uses this to "filter out" rows which are not expanded, which results in the effect of expanding/collapsing a tree in the table.

OK, so it works (yay!), but...

- it's not as flexible as the base `<b-table>`; if you want to show different columns of data, you'll need to do some work and to re-do the `<template slot="???">` sections for the columns as required.
- if you want to actually use filtering to filter the *content* (with a text search, for example) you'll need to extend the custom filter function to take this into account as well
- *sorting* the data is not something I had to do for my use case, and I'm not sure how it would work in the context of a tree structure anyway - maintaining the tree's parent/child relationships while changing the order of the rows around would be... fun, and I suspect this would be a nice challenge to implement for someone who is not as time poor as me. ;)

Anyway, I hope this is of use to someone. I'm reasonably new to Vue.js, so there may be a better way to approach this, but it's done the job I needed to get done.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Ahh... yeah, it is. I'll try and hunt down the source code from the original project and see if I can recreate the example (though it was almost two years ago now, and the project was a bit of a prototype and may have been binned by now). 

Thanks for the heads up, @LucianoBrum